# Python: Importing Libraries as Variables

Tags: python

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        install_package('abc')
        import abc
     def sq(self):
        print(abc.sqrt(5))
```

**Background**

I am writing helper classes (all stored in a `helper.py`) for my clients who use python to run a application(which I send them). These helper classes help the application function. To allow for quicker deployment on client side, I wrote a function called `install_package` that implicitly calls `pip install`.

All clients receive the same `helper.py` file but a different application. The application I send them usually use a subset of classes from `helper.py`.

**Motive**

So the reason I use the above class structure is now pretty obvious, I do not want to load all the libraries in the start of the `helper.py` as the libraries will have a corresponding `install_package()` with them. So for a client who's application may not use all the classes, there is no need to install all the unnecessary libraries

**Issue**

Now the issue is that using the above structure to `A()` seems like a feasible option but the package that I import in the `__init__` function does not get globally imported and hence `sq()` cannot use functions in the `abc` library. What's the best way to fix this? One way would be to store the library in a variable local to the `class`. How would I go about doing it? Suggestions to change the class structure also welcome!

Comment: Honestly, you say that the reason for this structure is “pretty obvious” but I don’t see it at all. Instead I suggest that you read up on app deployment using Python. This is a solved problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
import importlib

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        install_package('abc')
        self.abc = importlib.import_module('abc')
     def sq(self):
        print(self.abc.sqrt(5))
```

Comment: How would the import_module parameter be for from abc import def? Would it be 'abc.def'?

Comment: @MohitBhasi Yes, you could do `self.def = abc.def`. Or, something like `import abc.def as ghi` could "translate" as something like `self.ghi = abc.def`.